# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," 35 |

Tags: javascript

I am getting error in following code . Please review code and suggest fix. I exported this JS code from Selenium IDE. Please look into this and share fix.

I am getting error in following code . Please review code and suggest fix. I exported this JS code from Selenium IDE. Please look into this and share fix.

```
// New Relic Synthetics Formatter for Selenium IDE
// Feel free to explore, or check out the full documentation
// https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/synthetics/new-relic-synthetics/scripting-monitors/writing-scripted-browsers
// for details


  const assert = require("assert");
  const urlRequest = require("urllib").request;
  // Theshold for duration of entire script - fails test if script lasts longer than X (in ms)
  // Script-wide timeout for all wait and waitAndFind functions (in ms)
  var DefaultTimeout = 30000;
  // Change to any User Agent you want to use.
  // Leave as "default" or empty to use the Synthetics default.
  var UserAgent = "default";
  const By = $driver.By;
  const browser = $browser.manage();
  var vars = new Map();
  const logger = function({timeout:e=18e4,stepLogging:t=!1,insightsKey:n=""}){const r=Date.now();var s=0,o="",i=0,a=0;function l({step:e=0,msg:t="",duration:r=0,eventType:s="SyntheticsCustom",custom:o={}}){if(void 0===n||""==n)return;var i={method:"POST",headers:{"X-Insert-Key":n,"Content-Type":"application/json"},data:{eventType:s,step:e,message:t,duration:r,JOB_ID:$env.JOB_ID,MONITOR_ID:$env.MONITOR_ID,ACCOUNT_ID:$env.ACCOUNT_ID,LOCATION:$env.LOCATION,PROXY_HOST:$env.PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT:$env.PROXY_PORT},dataType:"text"};const a=`https://insights-collector.newrelic.com/v1/accounts/${$env.ACCOUNT_ID}/events`;i.data=Object.assign({},i.data,o),urlRequest(a,i)}function c(e,t,n=""){e>a&&0!=a&&_({testCase:n});let i=`Step ${e}: ${t} STARTED at ${s=Date.now()-r}ms. testCase=${n}`;console.log(i),o=t,a=e}function _({testCase:i=""}){var c=Date.now()-r,_=c-s;if(console.log(`Step ${a}: ${o} FINISHED. It took ${_}ms to complete. testCase=${i}`),t&&n.length>0?l({step:a,msg:o,duration:_,custom:{testCase:i}}):t&&$util.insights.set(`Step ${a}: ${o}`,_),e>0&&c>e)throw new Error("Script timed out. "+c+"ms is longer than script timeout threshold of "+e+"ms.")}return{logStep:function(e){c(i++,e)},log:c,getStep:function(){return i},end:_,endTestCase:function(e=""){var i=Date.now()-r-s;console.log(`Step ${a}: ${o} FINISHED. It took ${i}ms to complete.`),t&&n.length>0?l({step:a,msg:o,duration:i,custom:{testCase:e}}):t&&$util.insights.set(`Step ${a}: ${o}`,i),$util.insights.set("testCase",e),$util.insights.set("testCaseStatus","Pass"),t&&n.length>0&&l({eventType:"SyntheticsTests",custom:{testCase:e,testCaseStatus:"Pass"}})},error:function(e,r=""){console.log(`Error in Step ${a}: ${o}`),$util.insights.set("errorStep",""+a),$util.insights.set("errorMsg",e.message),$util.insights.set("errorLineNumber",e.lineNumber),$util.insights.set("testCase",r),$util.insights.set("testCaseStatus","fail"),t&&n.length>0&&l({eventType:"SyntheticsTests",custom:{testCase:r,testCaseStatus:"Fail"}})},postInsights:l}}({})
  $browser.getCapabilities().then(function () { })
  // Test Case: BorrowerVerifyBorrowerComingFromEmswpPageLandsOnLoanAmountPage
  .then(function (){
    return Promise.resolve(true)

    .then( function(){return logger.log(1,"Open URL https://www.abcd.com/aaa","BorrowerVerifyBorrowerComingFromEmswpPageLandsOnLoanAmountPage"),$browser.get("https://www.abcd.com/aaa").then(e=>e)})
    .then(_=>{
      return $browser.executeScript("return window.location.href")
      .then(function(result){
        vars.set("url", result)
        return Promise.resolve(true)
      })
    })
    .then(function Echo(){
      console.log(vars.get("url"))
    })
    .then( _=>{ vars.set("urSplPricing", https://www.abcd.com/aaa/special-pricing);)
      if ($browser.executeScript("return (arguments[0] == arguments[1])", vars.get("url"),vars.get("urSplPricing"))) {
        .then( function(){return logger.log(2,"Click By.id(\"link-qtth5eyehu\")","BorrowerVerifyBorrowerComingFromEmswpPageLandsOnLoanAmountPage"),$browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.id("link-qtth5eyehu"),DefaultTimeout).then(e=>(e.click(),Promise.resolve(!0)))})
        } else {
          .then(function Echo(){
            console.log("emswp landing page displayed")
          })
          .then( function(){return logger.log(3,"Click By.id(\"link-2hwa6q3f2mj\")","BorrowerVerifyBorrowerComingFromEmswpPageLandsOnLoanAmountPage"),$browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.id("link-2hwa6q3f2mj"),DefaultTimeout).then(e=>(e.click(),Promise.resolve(!0)))})
          }
        })
        .then( function(){return logger.log(4,"Click By.id(\"confirmation_number\")","BorrowerVerifyBorrowerComingFromEmswpPageLandsOnLoanAmountPage"),$browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.id("confirmation_number"),DefaultTimeout).then(e=>(e.click(),Promise.resolve(!0)))})
        .then( function(){return logger.log(5,"Type \"TEST1234\" using locator By.id(\"confirmation_number\")","BorrowerVerifyBorrowerComingFromEmswpPageLandsOnLoanAmountPage"),$browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.id("confirmation_number"),DefaultTimeout).then(e=>(e.sendKeys("TEST1234"),Promise.resolve(!0)))})
        .then( function(){return logger.log(6,"Click By.id(\"hero__cta\")","BorrowerVerifyBorrowerComingFromEmswpPageLandsOnLoanAmountPage"),$browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.id("hero__cta"),DefaultTimeout).then(e=>(e.click(),Promise.resolve(!0)))})
        .then(function Sleep(){
          return $browser.sleep(1000)
        })
        .then( function(){return logger.log(7,"Click By.id(\"hero__cta\")","BorrowerVerifyBorrowerComingFromEmswpPageLandsOnLoanAmountPage"),$browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.id("hero__cta"),DefaultTimeout).then(e=>(e.click(),Promise.resolve(!0)))})
        .then( function(){return logger.log(8,"Verify Text Welcome! Let’s get started using By.css(\".loan-amount__SupHeadline-btbcct-1\")","BorrowerVerifyBorrowerComingFromEmswpPageLandsOnLoanAmountPage"),$browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.css(".loan-amount__SupHeadline-btbcct-1"),DefaultTimeout).then(e=>e.getText().then(e=>(assert.strictEqual("Welcome! Let’s get started",e),Promise.resolve(!0))))})
    .then(function() {
        logger.endTestCase("BorrowerVerifyBorrowerComingFromEmswpPageLandsOnLoanAmountPage");
    }, function(err) {
        logger.error (err, "BorrowerVerifyBorrowerComingFromEmswpPageLandsOnLoanAmountPage");
        throw(err);
    });

  })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please provide more specific debugging information about the problem you have observed, including which specific operation produces the error and what attempt you have made to correct the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please provide more specific debugging information about the problem you have observed, including which specific operation produces the error and what attempt you have made to correct the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: What line does it actually point to?

Comment: "I am too lazy to look at any IDE/tool for five seconds, so let me paste this to SO and have someone fix my typo for me"

Answer (score -1):

Look at your line 35... -_-

As ASDFGerte said : ""I am too lazy to look at any IDE/tool for five seconds, so let me paste this to SO and have someone fix my typo for me""